# MySQL, IF statement, variables, and NULL

Tags: mysql, null

After struggling for too long with something that should have been simple, I had a question to ask, but while writing it, I kept looking for solutions and I finally found the solution. I am posting it here anyway in case someone else has the same problem I had.

Description: get max value of a field from database. If that value is null, make it 1, otherwise increase it by one. Insert new record with that value.

Code I was trying:

```
select @nextNumber := max(number)+1 from test;
if @nextNumber == NULL then @nextNumber := 1;
insert into test (number) values (@nextNumber);
```

Turns out, the `if` statement can't stand on its own, at least not here.

Will put working code as an answer.

Comment: This is the wrong way to generate sequences. Please see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108200/what-is-the-correct-implementation-of-handling-concurrent-sql-inserts-while-ensu)

Comment: @mustaccio yeah, that seems overly complex to me. At least for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO test (number)
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(number), 1)
FROM test;
```

**UPDATE**

If record(s) exists we need in the next value. So:

```
INSERT INTO test (number)
SELECT 1 + COALESCE(MAX(number), 0)
FROM test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are re-inventing `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Is there some reason not to use that feature?

Comment: The way I've designed it, auto-increment does not apply here because the field in question counts from 1 to n and then resets and starts at 1 again each season. This probably means my design could be improved.

Comment: Is there another column that gives the "season"?  If so, that should really be part of the Question.  Then you have a 2-column `PRIMARY KEY` (for example).  That question has been discussed often.

Comment: yeah, based on your comments, clearly my design needs to be greatly improved. Live and learn. I'll go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score -2):

The code that works:

```
select @nextNumber := max(number) from test;
select @nextNumber := IF(@nextNumber IS NULL, 1, @nextNumber+1);
insert into test (number) values (@nextNumber);
```

This inserts 1 the first time, then 2, then 3, etc. Exactly what I want.

Comment: 1) 3 queries whereas 1 is enough. 2) What if 2 parallel querypacks?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "2 parallel querypacks," so your comment is lost on me. I didn't know about `coalesce`, so thank you for that.

Comment: *I have no idea what you mean by "2 parallel querypacks,"* I mean that when two (or more) separate processes/client executes the code in question, it is possible that they will obtain and insert the same `@nextNumber` values. It can be wrong by logic, and ever give dup error if unique index exists.